# Scrapping data using Network, Fetch, Response

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap the data from the website "https://kgis.ksrsac.in/election/AssemblyEng.aspx?Asmbcd=94" where "Asmbcd=" varies from 1 to 200.

Particularly I want to get the candidates' data for the 2018 Vote details. I could see the data source at Network -> Fethch/XHR -> Response.

I am fairly new to scrapping so any help would be very helpful:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://kgis.ksrsac.in/election/Election.asmx/GetPollingStationCandidateVotes"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"id": "GridData"})

rows = table.find_all("tr")
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 3:
        candidate = cells[0].text.strip()
        party = cells[1].text.strip()
        votes = cells[2].text.strip()
        print(candidate, party, votes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly. To get all candidates data you can try using their Ajax API:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


api_url = (
    "https://kgis.ksrsac.in/election/Election.asmx/GetPollingStationCandidateVotes"
)
payload = {"ac_code": "95", "PS": "208", "YR": "2018"}


all_data = []
for ac_code in range(1, 2):  # <-- increase from 1 to 200
    ps = 1
    payload['ac_code'] = ac_code
    while True:
        print(ac_code, ps)
        payload['PS'] = ps
        data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
        data = json.loads(data['d'])
        if not data:
            break
        for name, count in data[0].items():
            all_data.append({
                'ac_code': ac_code,
                'booth': ps,
                'name': name,
                'count': int(count)
            })
        ps += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.head(10))
```

Prints:

```
   ac_code  booth                             name  count
0        1    240            KAKSO PANDURANG PATIL    368
1        1    240               KAMAT RAMESH ISWAR      5
2        1    240       JOLLE SHASHIKALA ANNASAHEB    173
3        1    240            ROHINI SHRIMANT DIXIT      0
4        1    240    VIJAYLAKSHMI APPASAHEB KURANE      0
5        1    240          SACHIN KALLAPPA MADHALE      0
6        1    240              ANIL SHIVAJI KAMATE      1
7        1    240  JAYARAM PARASHRAM MIRAJAKARKAKA      0
8        1    240           SHARAD RAMAGOUDA PATIL      3
9        1    240         SAMBHAJI BAPU SOTHORAVAT      2
```

Prints: